# Using foreach with Jagged Arrays

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

```
int[][] myArray = new int[10][];

foreach (int[] eachArray in myArray) {
eachArray = new int[2]
}
```

I believe it should create an array that is

```
{ 0 , 0 }
{0 , 0}
.........
```

Jagged array is so confusing.....

Comment: Sorry for confusion I will add more deetails

Comment: In previous question, you was given an answer with documentation. There you will find answer for this question to.

Comment: Arrays are not confusing.. please post an actual question not just code that you expect us to know what it is you're thinking or having issues with..thanks

Comment: Jagged arrays are not that confusing, if you think of it as an array of arrays: it behaves just like any other array, but its items are arrays too...

Comment: If jagged arrays are confusing, use a `List<List<int>>` instead. It has also the advantage that it's resizable without overhead(copying into another array).

Comment: Using list sounds awesome. I like that way better. Less confusing too

Comment: @user1143720: What's confusing in `myList.Add(myOtherList)`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I meant that using List seems not confusing. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not create the jagged array you are looking for.  It's attempting to assign a new `int[2]` instance to the iteration variable, not to the slot in the original array.  This won't even compile as the iteration variable is treated as `readonly` by the compiler

The way to do this is with a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++) {
  myArray[i] = new int[2];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however should I always use that approach? It seemed using for loop is quite ugly to me... Is there any prettier way to do it?

Comment: @user1143720 the `for` loop is the standard way of doing it. It can be done with a full blown initializer but that requires initializing the entire array inline.

Comment: sorry for this dumb question. I will do more research before I post next question.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning to loop variables inside `foreach` loop is not allowed. You need a regular `for` loop with a counter, or you can try something slightly fancier:

```
int[][] myArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new int[2]).ToArray();
```